# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'read_file'

Tags: python, tensorflow, readfile, attributeerror

I am trying to run this code:

```py
from pandas.io.parsers.readers import read_table

from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_io_ops import read_file

t_x, t_y = next(valid_gen)
```

But I always get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'read_file'.
```

I found that in many comments they mention that the function has been moved into the tensorflow.io module. Any one can help me to resolve this issue ?
Thanks

Comment: I think it's `tf.io.read_file` but maybe just look in the docs?

Comment: Can you please confirm if tensorflow installed properly in your system and you can access it? Because I am able to access both libraries successfully in Google Colab. You may provide some more details on code or like TF version, platform or OS detail to understand the issue and fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

As you have rightly mentioned, the function has been moved into the tensorflow.io module.

Here is the code for your reference to get it corrected:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.io.read_file(
    filename, name=None
)
```

Example :

```
with open("/tmp/file.txt", "w") as f:
  f.write("asdf")


tf.io.read_file("/tmp/file.txt")
```

Here is the official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/read_file) regarding it.